# ASCIIEncoding and Lower Control Characters

Tags: c#, character-encoding

I expected my test code:

```
string Test = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 });
```

to return a string containing "????" however it doesn't. How can I get an ASCII encoding of a set of bytes where all the control characters and top-bit-set characters are converted to '?'?

Thanks, Andy

Update:

I guess my question should have been: How do I get StreamWriter to output only printable ASCII characters? I need to generate text files that will work with ancient programs that will freak out on control characters in the file.

Comment: Lower control characters *can* be validly encoded/decoded via ASCII. I'm not sure why you would expect them to be `?` - that is usually a substitute for things *outside* the encoding's capability, which *cannot* be represented.

Comment: OK, I asked the wrong question. Here is what I am doing
using(StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(Stream, new ASCIIEncoding())) {
Writer.Write((char)0x03));
}

I was hoping the conversion would be automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic conversion to ? per-se. Usually ? is a representation of unreadable chars imposed by a host program.

However, if your intention is to convert these so the user sees a ? instead, try this code:

```
string newStr = "";
foreach (char c in MyString) {
    if ((int.Parse(c) < 32)) {
        c = "?";
    }
    newStr = (newStr + c.ToString);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to avoid that because I am using a textwriter with this encoding. The example I gave is simplified.

Comment: the `newStr = (newStr + c.ToString)` is horrible here, but other than that it is a good answer. I would strongly suggest using `ToCharArray()`, iterating over that by index, then creating a `new string(theCharArray)`

Comment: There isn't many other ways to do that kind of conversion, unfortunately (a matter of efficiency really). But please note you would probably want to do an exception for char 13 and 10 (CR, LF).

Comment: @Marc it was just for example. Point is you would need to traverse the array one way or another.